# How to detect mouse hover on an image drawn from paintComponent's drawImage(); method

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, mouselistener, mousehover

I am new to Java and need help. I am making a GUI for an application using images made from photoshop, and want to create a menu using images which highlights when user hover mouse over them. I have tried `mouseEntered();` method by getting mouse x, y co-ordinates but it's not working. Here is the code.

```
public class GUI extends JComponent{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon exitBtnImg = new ImageIcon("src/images/userInterface/exitBtn.png");
        g.drawImage(exitBtnImg.getImage(), 0, 5, this);
        mouseHandler handler = new mouseHandler();
        addMouseListener(handler);
    }
}


public class mouseHandler implements MouseListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

   }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        if((e.getX()>100&&e.getX()<300)&&(e.getY()>50&&e.getY()<196)){

            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, don't load resources in `paintComponent`, your paint method should run as fast as it can, second, don't add listeners within the `paint` methods, this will get called a lot, so you're just repeatedly adding new listeners each time your component is painted

Comment: *"want to create a menu using images which highlights when user hover mouse over them"*  Put the images (normal and hover) into a `JButton` that has had the extra space and borders removed.  It will be much simpler, and probably better.  E.G. as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't load resources in `paintComponent`, your paint method should run as fast as it can
2. Don't add listeners within the `paint` methods, this will get called a lot, so you're just repeatedly adding new listeners each time your component is painted
3. Use a `MouseMotionListener` instead of a `MouseListener`, you want the `mouseMoved` event
4. You need some way to know where the image is painted, so you can determine if the mouse moved within it's bounds.

Have a look at [How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

This example uses a simple `Rectangle` to define the location that the image is painted within, when the mouse moves within the confines of that `Rectangle`, a flag is set and the component is repainted, which paints a alpha based highlight effect over the image

[image: Hover]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private Rectangle drawRectangle;
        private boolean highlight = false;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            img = ImageIO.read(...);
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    highlight = drawRectangle.contains(e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }

            });

            int width = getPreferredSize().width;
            int height = getPreferredSize().height;

            int x = (width - img.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (height - img.getHeight()) / 2;

            drawRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(img, drawRectangle.x, drawRectangle.y, this);
            if (highlight) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
                g2d.fill(drawRectangle);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Now, having said all that, you might be better off using the `rollover` capabilities of `JButton`, which will basically do the same thing.

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your reply the hover problem is solved , How can i use images in paintComponent if it is not correct to load them in paintcomponent ? where should i load them ? actually whole frame will be repainted after any event occur.

Comment: I loaded mine in the classes constructor